# How to make an all-vs-one group of scatterplots - a list of columns against one target column

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I want to plot a bunch of variables against the same target variable. So a kind of [scatter matrix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot-matrix), but with list_of_df_columns-vs-one_df_column rather than all-vs-all.

I've looked at adding subplots one by one in a loop, but it seems like there must be a better way. Is there some way to use the scatter_matrix function to do this?

There are dozens of variables I want to plot against a single outcome, I really want the results to be nice and compact so they can be presented as a single figure.

Answer (score 7):

You could try using seaborn pairplot, and passing specific x and y variables.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(df, y_vars="A", x_vars=df.columns.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the bare `plot` could help if you set the index to the fixed column:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[2,0,3,6,1,3],'C':[7,3,2,1,5,0],'D':[1,3,0,2,2,6]})

col = 'A'
df2 = df.drop(col,axis=1)
df2.index = df[col]
df2.plot(subplots=True, style='.')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There are waaaayyy too many rows and variables to plot on the same chart and colour each series differently. I need to produce a panel of scatterplots sort-of-like in that scatter matrix example I linked to, but all_variables-vs-one. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot-matrix

Comment: Humm, I think `scatter_matrix` doesn't provide such functionality but if I understood you now, the edit to my answer could help you

Comment: This produces a line plot. How can I produce a scatter plot? passing `kind=scatter` to the plot function gives `ValueError: scatter requires and x and y column`

Comment: @HarryPalmer No, you should use `style='.'` or another style of point like `style='d'`